# How to make PDO select queries HTML safe?

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm new to PDO and just started using it. I already inserted, updated and deleted data using it and it's very simple to use the basics.

In a test environment I inserted some HTML codes to the database. Like:

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
<b>Bold text</b>
<u>Underlined text</u>
```

etc...

I'm trying this out, because I'm using a simple WYSIWYG editor on my site for the users and I want to be sure the data is safe.

Using the following:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM naruto WHERE id = :id AND name = :name");

/*** bind the paramaters ***/
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 5);


/*** execute the prepared statement ***/
$stmt->execute();

/*** fetch the results ***/
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

/*** loop of the results ***/
foreach($result as $row)
    {
    echo $row['id'].'<br />';
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['image'];
    }
```

Where name is the different HTML codes, the HTML is just executed. So the text is bold and not in the format text< /b>.

I'm wondering if there is a function for PDO to stop this. Or do I just need to use htmlentities and strip_tags?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases don't particularly care whether the data stored in them is HTML markup or not, and neither do database abstraction layers such as PDO... it's just a string as far as they are concerned. It's up to you to handle the data as HTML or plain text.

Answer (score 2):

Using parameterised queries will protect your database from bad data. It won't protect your HTML as that is a completely different layer.

If you want to allow *some* HTML, then you need to run the data (just before you display it to the user) through something that will white list the HTML you want to allow.

I believe [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is one of the tools of choice for PHP users wanting to do this.

Comment: Awesome. That's what I've been looking for! Thank you very much!